# Multiple order by and null values to be ordered using next fields not to be first or last

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table like below,

```
|Product |Brand  |Order           |Description          |
---------------------------------------------------------
|TTT     | CCC   | 1              | FFF                 |
|EEE     | DDD   | 2              | DDD                 |
|ZZZ     | BBB   | 99             | NULL                |
|NNN     | FFF   | 99             | NULL                |
|QQQ     | EEE   | NULL           | NULL                |
|BBB     | FFF   | 1              | FFF                 |
|BBB     | GGG   | 1              | CCC                 |
|GGG     | NULL  | NULL           | NULL                |
|MMM     | BBB   | 99             | NULL                |
```

I want to order by Order asc, Description asc, Brand asc, Product asc,
but Order null and 99 should be considered as one group and then sort by Brand and Product.

Expected Result should be like below,

```
|Product | Brand |Order           |Description          |
---------------------------------------------------------
|BBB     | GGG   | 1              | CCC                 |
|TTT     | CCC   | 1              | FFF                 |
|BBB     | FFF   | 1              | FFF                 |
|EEE     | DDD   | 2              | DDD                 |
|MMM     | BBB   | 99             | NULL                |
|ZZZ     | BBB   | 99             | NULL                |
|QQQ     | EEE   | NULL           | NULL                |
|NNN     | FFF   | 99             | NULL                |
|GGG     | NULL  | NULL           | NULL                |
```

Always the null goes first or last, but I need a query to use different field sorting according to each condition.

Comment: What do you mean by "Order null and 99 should be considered as one group"?

Comment: When order is 99 or NULL then it should do sorting based on only Brand and Product. thanks

Comment: So it means that if it's 99 or NULL, it should be at the end of the result list, right?

Comment: When description is not null then it should be ordered by Order, Description, Brand and Product (Can be considered as ranking 0). When Order is null or 99 ( can be considered as ranking 1) and it should be ordered by Brand and Product. When everything is null other than Product (Ranking 2) and it should be ordered by Product. In another way each ranking should have different column to be used for sorting. Thanks

Comment: You can use [COALESCE](http://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/functions/coalesce.php) for replacing the `NULL` values with anything you want, for example if you consider `NULL` and `99` to be the same, use `COALESCE(Order, 99)` in your `ORDER` clause.

Comment: Already I have tried COALESCE, didn't help me for the Order. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such exceptions can be handled with [CASE expressions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case).

When `Order` is NULL, it should be handled like 99, so replace NULL with 99.
When `Order` is NULL or 99, the description should be ignored, so in this case, replace `Description` with a fixed value:

```
SELECT ...
ORDER BY CASE WHEN "Order" IS NULL THEN 99 ELSE "Order" END,
         CASE WHEN "Order" IS NULL OR "Order" = 99 THEN 0 ELSE Description END,
         Brand,
         Product;
```

Comment: SELECT ...
ORDER BY CASE WHEN "Order" IS NOT NULL AND "Description" IS NOT NULL THEN "Order"
         ELSE CASE WHEN "Brand" IS NOT NULL THEN "Brand" ELSE 'ZZZZZZ' END END, Order, Description, Brand, Product.
         Brand,
         Product;

Comment: Actually //'ZZZZZZ' will be internally assigned to the Brand which are null, so that the items will be last in the list. Thanks everyone